# Why can I not compare chrono::weekday's with operator<()?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

In the new C++20 `<chrono>` header there is a `std::chrono::weekday` type.  Why can I not compare `weekday`s with `operator<` and thus sort them?

```
auto wd1 = Wednesday;
auto wd2 = Thursday;
if (wd1 < wd2)  // compile-time error
{
    // do something
}

test.cpp:14:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression (std::chrono::weekday and 
std::chrono::weekday)
if (wd1 < wd2)
    ~~~ ^ ~~~
```

Isn't Wednesday less than Thursday?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the view of `<chrono>`, no `Wednesday` is not less than `Thursday`.

`Thursday - Wednesday` does indeed equal `days{1}`.  However `Wednesday - Thursday` equals `days{6}`, not `days{-1}`.

In modern culture, there is [disagreement about which day is the first day of the week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#:%7E:text=While%2C%20for%20example%2C%20the%20United,first%20day%20of%20the%20week.).  The `<chrono>` library takes the view that we do not have to agree on which day is the first day of the week.  We can do meaningful computations with days of the week without such agreement.

To facilitate such computations, `<chrono>` views the weekdays as an independent calendar that repeats itself every 7 days, with absolutely no difference between any of the 7 day cycles.  Monday follows Sunday, Thursday follows Wednesday, and Sunday follows Saturday.  It is a circular range of seven values with no beginning and no end.

As a practical matter, there are two popular encodings of weekdays in terms of integral values:

1. C encodes [Sunday, Saturday] as [0, 6].
2. ISO encodes [Monday, Sunday] as [1, 7].

`<chrono>` acknowledges this by accepting [0, 7] in the `weekday` constructor to mean `Sunday`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, `Friday`, `Saturday`, `Sunday`, respectively.  And to enable the reverse transformation `weekday` has two member functions:

1. `c_encoding()`
2. `iso_encoding()`

which return the integral value associated with the stored `weekday` according to those two protocols (0 or 7 for Sunday, and 1 thru 6 for Monday thru Saturday).

**However, the underlying encoding of `std::chrono::weekday` should be considered an unimportant detail for computations involving `weekday`.**

`std::chrono::weekday` is a circular range of 7 values.  No value is greater than any other value.  They are either equal or not equal.

Difference between any two `weekday` values (say `x` and `y`) results in the number of `days` `x` is ahead of `y`.  This is true, no matter what numerical encoding you imagine represents `weekday` under the hood.

And this means that `Wednesday` is not less than `Thursday`.  `Wednesday` is 6 days ahead of `Thursday`, and `Thursday` is 1 day ahead of `Wednesday`.

This design enables computations such as "what is the next Monday from this date" without depending on the underlying encoding:

```
std::chrono::sys_days
next_monday(std::chrono::sys_days x)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return x + (Monday - weekday{x});
}
```

In English:

How many days is `x`'s weekday behind Monday?  Add that many days to `x`.

Comment: At the very least, `Monday` should clearly be less than `Friday` though. Can we make an exception :-)

Comment: Maybe we should add "enjoyment points" to the weekdays. :-)

Comment: Affine answer.  As module is to vector space, an affine space is to what?  But I guess Z_7 is a field, so the space of weekdays is an affine space?